# Issue with applying CSS styles to EJS templates in an application using API Gateway

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm facing an issue with applying CSS styles in my Node.js web application that uses API Gateway. I'm using Express.js for my server and EJS for templates.

I have set up my static files like this in my Express application:

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

And in my EJS templates, I include my CSS files like this:

However, when I access my application, no styles are applied. Looking into the browser's developer tools, I can see that the CSS files are loaded, but the styles are not applied correctly.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with API Gateway? How can I resolve this problem and ensure that my styles are applied correctly?

[![enter image description here][3]][3]
*
Thank you in advance for your help!*
Don't forget to include additional details about your configuration, relevant code, and any troubleshooting steps you have already tried.

when i use the absolute path it's work correctly

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: `when i use the absolute path it's work correctly` points very likely to the issue of a wrong relative path. I assume your folder structure is something like `/public/css/slick.css`, then instead of `css/slick.css` try `/css/slick.css`